# Ошибка типов "NoneType object is not callable"

Tags: python

Добрый вечер.
Хотелось бы узнать, как избавиться от данной ошибки.

```
itemDesc.replace(';', '')
```

В этой строке возникает ошибка, в данной переменной находится html код. 
Происходит ошибка:

> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Уже разобрался, понимал, что нужно переменную объявить строкой, но вот такой вариант почему-то не работал

```
itemDesc = str(itemDesc)
```

Подсказали вот так:

```
itemDesc = itemDesc.__str__().replace('', '')<br>
```

Заработало.

Answer (score 5):

Надо верить Питону. 
Ваш объект **itemDesc** имеет тип **NoneType**. Для него нет метода **replace**
Вы пишите, что в переменной находится html код, но видимо это не так.
Проверяйте тип и действуйте в зависимости от результата.

```
>>> type(itemDesc)
```

http://docs.python.org/library/types.html#types.NoneType

http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#string.replace